# Error with my concatentation in php?

Tags: php, concatenation

I have the following, which is not outputting "OK" in my browser.  I assume the concatenation is wrong.  I would be grateful for any help.  Cheers.

```
<?php
$x = array("submit","submit1");

foreach ($x as $value){
if ((isset($_POST['$value . "_" . " x"']))){
echo "OK";
}
?>
```

I want the content of $_POST to be submit_x, submit1_x etc

As requested, print_r($POST) gives in the browser:

```
OK
Notice: Undefined index: submit1_x in C:\xampp\htdocs\lotto\test1.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it more complicated than it needed to be:

```
 $_POST[$value . "_x"]
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST)` for me and add it to your question. That will help troubleshooting.